# Can I call the GNOME restart confirmation prompt from the command line?

Tags: gnome, command-line, reboot

When I click [image: Indicator Applet Session] --> Restart, the following prompt appears:

[image: screenshot]

Can I cause this to appear from the command line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper -r` will do it.

Note that this is not the upstream GNOME restart dialog; it's specific to indicator-session. You'd invoke the GNOME one with `gnome-session-save --shutdown-dialog`.